# Tabla dinámica con PHP

Tags: php

Estoy intentando generar una tabla dinámica en PHP, pero no hay manera. A ver si alguien me echa una mano.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<!-- Genero columna -->
echo "
    <table> 
        <thead>
            <th class='_160px'></th>
            <th>$fecha</th>
        </thead>
    <table>";

for ($i=0; $i<($filas-1); $i++){ //Genera las filas de la tabla 
    echo "
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>$array[$i]</td>               
        </tr>     
    </table>
    <br>";   

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        extract($fila);    
        echo"
            <td> $NumeroFabricacion + </td>            
        ";
    }
```

Mi problema es que no consigo que los datos que itera el while queden en linea con la linea generada por el $array[$i].

Comment: Fijate el html generado.. no es que no quedan en linea, son tablas distintas... tenes una sola tabla, con lo cual, deberias tener una sola etiqueta table.. y luego no se que es array[i], pero esta en otra tabla distitna...

Comment: Pero ... por cada etiqueta de apertura, tienes que tener una de cierre. Si quieres dos columnas por fila, tienes que tener '<tr><td>lo que sea</td><td>otra cosa</td><tr>' y como te indica gbianchi,  hay demasiadas etiquetas table. Y mal balanceadas (una abre, otra cierra). Deberías repasar cómo se define una tabla, hacer lo que quieres de forma estática y luego ya añadir el código PHP para que te genere dinámicamente las filas.

Comment: Tienes varias cosas mal, para empezar, no puedes generar el tbody en una tabla distina a las filas, en el primer bucle, tal vez quieras cambiar table por tbody. Tampoco puedes iniciar un table o tbody por cada fila, eso generaría una tabla por cada fila. Tampoco puedes iniciar un bucle por cada $fila y luego asignar a $fila un resultado de sql, eso rompe el bucle... te sugiero lo mismo que RubioRic, haz la tabla en html y luego reemplaza las cosas con php... será lo más sencillo.

Comment: Te voy ha hacer una respuesta con una tabla genérica un poco basada en la tuya, pero no tengo los datos del SQL ni demás, así que no será una respuesta directa a tu problema particular.

Answer (score 1):

Para crear una tabla desde PHP, lo primero será tener claro cómo va a ser la tabla una vez generada, por ejemplo, dos columnas. Además, deberás tener en cuenta cómo es una tabla en html, por lo general será así:

```
<!-- Tabla genérica en HTML -->
<table>

    <!-- Definición de columnas -->
    <thead>
        <tr> <!-- El header solo tiene una fila -->
            <th>Columna 1</th>
            <th>Columna 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <!-- Contenido de las filas -->
    <tbody>
        <tr> <!-- Primera fila -->
            <td>Dato columna 1</td>
            <td>Dato columna 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Segunda fila -->
            <td>Dato columna 1</td>
            <td>Dato columna 2</td>
        </tr>
    <!-- Cierras el cuerpo -->
    </tbody>
<!-- Cierras la tabla -->
</table>
```

Explicado esto, ahora solo queda generarlo desde PHP. En este caso del ejemplo, sería:

```
<?php

    $columnas = array(
        "k_col1" => "Columna 1",
        "k_col2" => "Columna 2"
    );
    $datos = array(
        array(
            "Dato 1 columna 1",
            "Dato 1 columna 2"
        ),
        array(
            "Dato 2 columna 1",
            "Dato 2 columna 2"
        ),
    );

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($columnas as $col) {
        echo "<th>" . $col . "</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";

    echo "<tbody>";
    foreach($datos as $dato) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $dato[0] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $dato[1] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

Claro, todo esto se puede simplificar o complicar mucho según tus necesidades. Te recomiendo mirar la documentación de table en https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp